# javascript var not updated (HTML+javascript+jquery)

Tags: jquery, scala, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a rather weird set of application's features : scala+spray(web framework)+twirl(web templates)+javascript+jquery.

anyway my issue comes from javascript & jquery:

I have in an html page these components:

```
<label for="from">De</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">à</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
```

The 2 inputs are changed to datePickers(jquery plugin) by this code:

```
$(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[""]);
        $("#from").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                dateFrom=jQuery('#from').val();
            }
        });
        $("#from").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);

        $("#to").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                dateTo=jQuery('#to').val();
            }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
    });
```

My problem comes from the 2 variables dateFrom & dateTo, initialized before the previous code (just after the script tag) by:

```
var firstTable;
    dateFrom="";
    dateTo="";
```

Finally, the 2 variables are used by this:

```
function myText() {
        alert("from : "+dateFrom)
        if (dateFrom == "" || dateTo == "") {
            return "A/B";
        } else {
            return ""+dateFrom+"/"+dateTo;   //+ jQuery('#from').val() + "/" + jQuery('#to').val();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        firstTable = $('#aTable').dataTable({
            "bPaginate" : false,
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
                "sWidth" : "50px",
                "aTargets" : [ 9 ]
            } ],
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "json/" + myText()
        });
    });
```

The important point is that even if I put a date in the 2 datepickers(by clicking on them) the myText() method returns "A/B" and not the javascript variables.
Moreover, at the loading of the html page, the alert in myText is displayed ("from : " and no date after the from) and this alert is not displayed at a second call, when I would have put the 2 dates.
Is there a cache of the myText method?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the variables `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. You can declare the variables as:

```
var firstTable;
var dateFrom="";
var dateTo="";
```

or as,

```
var firstTable, dateFrom="", dateTo="";
```

Also, it's good to check the browser inbuilt JS console, where such errors can be easily seen.

Comment: hello, even with 2 more "var" the error is still there.